# Android FFMpeg No such file or directory error

Tags: android, ffmpeg, crop

I am using ffmpeg for android (using the gradle plugin 'com.writingminds:FFmpegAndroid:0.3.2') and I am trying to crop a video to a 16:9 (w:h) ratio. The original video is 1080:1920 (w:h).
When I execute the command I get an IOException No such file or directory.

The command I am using:

```
-i /storage/emulated/0/Movies/MyApp/result_joined.mp4 -vf crop=1080:607   -preset ultrafast /storage/emulated/0/Movies/MyApp/result_cropped.mp4
```

The exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Error running exec(). Command: 
[/data/user/0/my.package.name/files/ffmpeg, -i, /storage/emulated/0/Movies/MyApp/result_joined.mp4, -vf, crop=1080:607, -preset, ultrafast, /storage/emulated/0/Movies/MyApp/result_cropped.mp4] Working Directory: null Environment: null
Caused by: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
```

After searching several stack overflow questions with no help.
I also tried to save files to internal storage instead of external storage. Same result

Any help?

Comment: As the error specifies, Either Your directory is not created or the file is not present there. You should make sure once again.

Comment: @lalith Thanks for your reply. I actually checked several times that the directory and file exist.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

You need to call *loadBinary* method after creating instance of **FFmpeg**.

```
try {
    ffmpeg.loadBinary(new LoadBinaryResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure() {
          Logger.i(TAG, "ffmpeg not supported");
        }
    });
} catch (FFmpegNotSupportedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is old, but trust me when I tell you that it is STILL a problem. (I only solved it for myself personally today (Saturday May 27, 2023), & NOT because of the answers here (or anywhere else).) Anyway, I'll use "FFmpeg media encoder" for android as my example. (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.silentlexx.ffmpeggui)

I've had that program for a LONG time, & I've tried searching the internet for just as long for an answer to why I kept getting the "No such file or directory" error. Today, after rereading the description for FFmpeg media encoder, I noticed that it says that for android 11+, INPUT files need to be in either Alarms, DCIM, Documents, Download, Movies, Music, or Pictures. My problem was that I personally hate those areas & use my own user created folders instead (for superior organization). I tested this by putting a video in the Music folder & then having (android) FFmpeg work with it, & it WORKED!

So if you want to use (android) FFmpeg with something, put your input files in one of those folders. Also, spread the message about this solution, because this is STILL a major source of FFmpeg FAILURES for a LOT of people.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @bot
Staying that you did not READ what I potsed is an undestatement. (Yes, I know that a bot can't really understand what it reads., but that's beside my point.) I gave ALL of the information that my post can use, & I'm keeping it AS IT IS. If you 'think' that I/it violated any rules, report it to a REAL human moderator & I'll accept THEIR judgement.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this library

```
implementation 'com.arthenica:mobile-ffmpeg-full-gpl:4.2.2.LTS'
```

FFmpeg.execute(cmd);

Command used is
cmd  String cmd = "-y -i " + oldPath + " -c:a copy -r 30 -vcodec libx264 -crf 28 -preset ultrafast " + newFile.getPath();

old path can be "storage/emulated/0/Download/input.mp4"

new path can be "storage/emulated/0/Download/output.mp4"

Answer (score -1):

I am getting same Exception. I forgot to load FFmpeg Library.
first we have to load this library.
Run this Function before Run The Command.

```
void LoadFFmpegLibrary()
{
    if(ffmpeg==null)
    {
        ffmpeg = FFmpeg.getInstance(context);
        try {
            ffmpeg.loadBinary(new LoadBinaryResponseHandler() {

                @Override
                public void onStart() {}

                @Override
                public void onFailure() {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {}
            });
        } catch (FFmpegNotSupportedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer is the same as [an already existing one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52399527).